# Attach loading gif for file upload using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I have a to upload image files to the server and correspondingly save their info in the database. Some of these files are big and take time to upload, so I need to incorporate a loading.gif when the upload is on using ajax. I also use the same AJAX function to prevent page refresh as I upload several images.

These are the two JS functions I am using

```
function showLoading(){
document.getElementById("loading").style = "visibility: visible";
}
function hideLoading(){
document.getElementById("loading").style = "visibility: hidden";
}
```

This is the AJAX

```
$(function () {
        $('form#data').submit(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            showLoading();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: 'upload.php',
                data: formData,
                async:false,
                cache:false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (returndata) {
                    $('#result').hideLoading().html(returndata);
                        alert("Data has been Uploaded: ");
                    }

            });
            return false;
        }); 
});
```

This is the image tag

```
<img id='loading' src='loading.gif' style='visibility: hidden;'>
```

When I click submit, i can only see the loading.gif. It previously used to tell me that the file has been uploaded and returned the input details. Also I need the loading.gif to hide once the file has been uploaded.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: On Success function you need to call hide function, `hideLoading();$('#result')..html(returndata);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
      $('#result').hideLoading().html(returndata);
```

you're calling `hideloading()` as if it was a JQuery method. it's not, so that code is a syntax error: call to undefined method.

You should have

```
success: function() {
    hideLoading();
}
```

And note that your code simply assumes success. If the upload fails for whatever reason, you'll STILL be showing the loading gif. You should move that hide call to a `complete` handler instead, so that regardless of the success/failure, the gif will hide when the ajax call is done.

Comment: it did not work the way I expected so I implemented a progress bar. Its working but not resetting for subsequent file uploads. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777837/progress-bar-for-file-uploads-to-php-using-ajax-and-bootstrap